# How to pass Tumbling Window parameters to a Data Factory pipeline in the Data Factory UI?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have defined a pipeline in `Azure Data Factory` with a Tumbling Window trigger, as seen below:

[image: Pipeline with the trigger]

I would like for my activities to receive the Tumbling window parameters (`trigger().outputs.windowStartTime` and `trigger().outputs.windowEndTime`) however I did not find any examples in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger) showing how to do this in the UI.

**Question**

How can I pass the Tumbling Window parameters to a Data Factory pipeline in the Data Factory UI?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the pipeline that you're triggering is already paramaterised then you're nearly there.

When adding the trigger you'll see a second screen to pass parameters from the trigger.

[image]

You can then add your functions prefixed with @. So:

```
@trigger().outputs.windowStartTime
@trigger().outputs.windowEndTime
```

If you need to call a function on the parameter before you pass it you can do that too

```
@addHours(trigger().outputs.windowEndTime,1)
```

Comment: Did they change the syntax? `The template language expression 'trigger().outputs.windowStartTime' cannot be evaluated because property 'outputs' doesn't exist, available properties are 'name, startTime, endTime, scheduledTime, trackingId, clientTrackingId, originHistoryName, code, status`

Comment: Ok, found the error. Scheduled and tumbling windows have slightly different [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables)

Comment: @MartinThøgersen what was the error and what was the fix?

Comment: @BlueClouds the error was that I used *tumbling* system variables for my *scheduled* trigger. It's clearly defined in [System variables supported by Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables)

Answer (score 2):

> This answer is out of date. Parameters can be added directly in the UI - see my answer above.

**Note:** You cannot pass the Tumbling Windows parameters to a Data Factory pipeline in the ADF UI.

You need to pass the tumbling window parameters by following steps:

First create a Tumbling window trigger as per your requirement.

On the bottom left corner, you will find the "**Triggers**" tab => Click on **Triggers** and select the created trigger and click on "**Code**" and replace the parameters.

[image]

To use the WindowStart and WindowEnd system variable values in the pipeline definition, use your "MyWindowStart" and "MyWindowEnd" parameters, accordingly.

[image]

For more details, refer "[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80fc8d7a-2c29-4a80-8e82-86b2913fc42c/tumbling-window-endtime-parameter-adfv2?forum=AzureDataFactory)" thread, which addressing similar issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This results in NULL being passed.

Comment: I still do not understand anything.Replace the parameter with what?  What does that line @{concat('output',... do ?

Comment: Hi @BlueClouds - I've marked this answer as out of date. The other answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you set `@trigger().outputs.windowStartTime` and `@trigger().outputs.windowEndTime` in the variable. In fact, you should set them in the parameter, like this:

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

Please let me know if still facing issue.