# How to get the windowStartTime with Tumbling Window trigger in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am actually working with the Azure Data Factory, So my aim is to run the pipeline from the specified start and end date.

So for that, I am using the Tumbling Window trigger for triggering the pipeline.

**Code:**

(`trigger().outputs.windowStartTime` and `trigger().outputs.windowEndTime`),

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

The expression 'trigger().outputs.windowStartTime' cannot be evaluated because property 'windowStartTime' doesn't exist, available properties are 'headers, body'.

**Question**

How can I pass the Tumbling Window parameters to a Data Factory pipeline in the Data Factory UI?

Comment: Seems, this would help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455863/how-to-pass-tumbling-window-parameters-to-a-data-factory-pipeline-in-the-data-fa?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set `trigger().outputs.windowStartTime` and `trigger().outputs.windowEndTime` in the variable. In fact, you should set them in the parameter, like this:

[image]

Then you need to check your `Trigger` code, if there aren't these parameters, you need to add them.

[image].

[image]